# Use asp.net to login for user?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys, so I'm working on an app that aggregates information for the user (eg. get search results from yahoo, google, etc. and put them in one window), but requires a logon/ authentication. Do you guys know how this can be done with asp.net or other windows server languages?

So here's another example: user goes to website, then website logs him into gmail, yahoo and hotmail, then pools all the emails together into the website.

Thank you!

EDIT: OK I think I need to clarify a little. What I'm planning on doing is having the web app log in to each website, then read the html for specific things like scores or whatnot. I know how to do nearly every part of this, except my concern is that since asp.net is server based it won't let me have 50 users online at the same time logged into different accounts (imagine facebook.com has 50 logins from the same server). I have tried doing this with javascript but I'm running into problems with browser permissions, so I'm considering other avenues.

Comment: Are you using the API for each platform, or are you just trying to screen scrape?

Comment: Those are two completely different things: aggregating search results and aggregating email inboxes...

Answer (score 0):

Well you are going to need to store credentials for all of the combined services.
Simple enough, encrypt them and throw them in the database once they have added gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc..

Use the built in ASP.NET membership provider initially, Forms Authentication, design a DB schema for the data you are wanting to store and code away.

Simple stuff.

Comment: *"Well you are going to need to store credentials for all of the combined services"* Seems like that could be a pretty big dealbreaker for this app; I can't imagine what kind of functionality a web app could offer me that would compel me to give it all of my email credentials. :P